# How to render child component with onclick event in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to render child component when I click the button

Parents

```js
const Parents:React.FC<PropTypes> = ({inputs}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => <Child props={inputs}/>}
    </div>
   )}
```

Child

```js
const Child:React.FC<AnotherPropTypes> = ({props}) => {
  // ... 
}
```

I am using React, TypeScript and Material-UI for it.
My question is that, it does not seem like `onClick` event trigger Child component. How can I run child component when I click the button?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add state to your component. The click event sets the state, and the state is used to decide whether or not to render extra things.

```
const Parents:React.FC<PropTypes> = ({inputs}) => {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  return(
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => setShowChild(true)} />
      {showChild && <Child props={inputs}/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it the React concept?